# Smplayer не запоминает последнюю позицию в файле

Tags: ubuntu

Вот мои настройки: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постоянно приходится писать время в файл, по-моему это примитивно. 
Кому-нибудь удалось решить эту проблему, не верю, что все пользуются шпаргалками.

Answer (score 0):

Короче не знаю точно если оно, но поигрался с интрефейсом и натолкнулся на такой интересный эффект.
Если нажать на желтую звездочку и добавить текущий файл в закладки, то в этом случае, плеер будет запоминать позицию в файле, только если опять же запустить файл из закладок.
Только остается вопрос, зачем нужны плейлисты, если плеер не запоминает позицию в файле. Пока что буду пользоваться этой возможностью.